# CALayer shadow with Spread & Size attributes?

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics, photoshop, shadow

i'm struggling creating a drop shadow around a CALayer. For the effect i'm trying to achieve i need to have access to the "intensity" of the shadow. Somehow like the "spread" slider in Photoshop's Layer Styles. I think the "ShadowRadius" property of CALayer is equivalent to Photoshop's "Size" slider.

Any suggestions? Is maybe a radial gradient an option?

Comment: You should try to illustrate your question with a before/after Photoshop screensot of the effect you want to apply.

Answer (score 7):

Set the layer's `shadowOffset`,`shadowOpacity`, and `shadowRadius` and you should have what you are looking for. Try this for a shadow project directly "underneath" the layer with a blur of 5 pixels, which with the right color, could also make it look like a glow:

```
CALayer *layer = myView.layer;
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.50;
layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
layer.shadowOffset = (CGSize){.width=0.0,.height=0.0};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. I'd like to control the "slope" of the shadow gradient. Kind of hard to explain..  The sharpness, maybe..

Comment: So, What do you mean by Spread ? is it shaddow Offset or Radius ?

Comment: Actually neither of those. I mean the intensity of the black (shadow color).

Answer (score 6):

You can control "spread" by setting custom shadowPath property on a CALayer.

```
CGFloat radius = CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds)/2.0;
// this is a sample code for a circle, but you can use any shape you want
CGPathRef shadowPathRef = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0 * radius, 2.0 * radius) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

layer.shadowPath = shadowPathRef;
```

If you set radius to a bigger value, shadow spread will be bigger.